# How to queue data for HTTP POST in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, mqtt

I am building a simple IoT project in which a micro-controller publishes sensor data to a MQTT broker every second on a particular topic. I am using Node.js to build an app that uses the mqtt library to subscribe to this topic and update the sensor data to the Thingspeak channel using their API via a POST request (using the request library).

I have managed to build something that is almost working but I am facing a slight problem. I am not able to update all the sensor data since the POST request takes some time and during that time other sensor data is also published.

I am thinking of a solution in which I can queue the sensor data that needs to be updated via POST request.

Here is my current code:

```
var mqtt = require("mqtt")
var request = require("request")

var client  = mqtt.connect('hostname')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('topic')
})

var postReq = function(data) {
  request.post('https://api.thingspeak.com/update', {form: {sensor_data: data}}, function(err,response,body){
    console.log(body)
  }}
}

client.on('message', function (topic, data) {
  // message is Buffer
  postReq(data)
})
```

Comment: `during that time other sensor data is also published.` Why don't you delay the other data post? Or make an async request to execute both at the same time.

Comment: Is `request` library synchronous or asynchronous ?